# PHP: Pass an associative arrays keys and values into a new array in a row (consecutive) without foreach

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simpler way than using a foreach loop to do a transformation like this?

```
$assoc = ['keyA' => 'valA', 'keyB' => 'valB', 'keyC' => 'valC'];

$new = ['keyA', 'valA', 'keyB', 'valB', 'keyC', 'valC'];
```

Comment: Depends, is it necessary to keep the order of the elements?

Comment: I think the cleanest way would be using a foreach loop

Answer (score 3):

With **array_walk** :

```
$assoc = ['keyA' => 'valA', 'keyB' => 'valB', 'keyC' => 'valC'];

$new = [];

$callback = function($v, $k) use (&$new) {
    $new[] = $k;
    $new[] = $v;
};
array_walk($assoc, $callback);

print_r($new);
```

Output :

> Array (
>       [0] => keyA
>       [1] => valA
>       [2] => keyB
>       [3] => valB
>       [4] => keyC
>       [5] => valC )

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: Not much simpler than a foreach loop

Comment: thought of array_walk. but not of using pointers. not much simpler, yes, but a solution. thanks

Comment: @Rizier123 agreed, I can't think of another way of building this exact result (w/ stacking order) apart from a foreach loop.